# About retracted flags and the comment persisting

Tags: support, duplicates, comments, flagging

Case in point: [How do I convert my usb installation from legacy boot to uefi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958558/how-do-i-convert-my-usb-installation-from-legacy-boot-to-uefi)

By mistake I flagged as duplicate but later on noticed it was about Elementary OS. Retracted but the comment persists?

Comment: Well the comment was posted under your name so you can remove it yourself, but it does look like this might be a bug.

Comment: Now the comment appears to have been removed.

Comment: Perhaps it needed time. I didn't removed it myself.

Comment: @MichaelBay the question was closed as a duplicate. When that happens, the comment created with the link to the duplicate is deleted. There's no need to delete it until then: *you* may retract your flag, but others can still VTC with the same question.